# Importing a sub-module from the parent package

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have the following package structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── common
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── analysis
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── base_analysis.py
│   ├── logger
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── logger.py
└── scripts
    └── test_analysis
        └── run.py
```

I would like to access logger in base_analysis.py. If I do this:

```
from ..logger import Logger
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How to import a sub-package from the parent package?

Note: I am running the script from scripts/test_analysis using:

```
python run.py
```

Comment: Move base_analysis.py up a level or use the full path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: probable dupe  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72852/674039

Comment: See if [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) helps.

Comment: OK; now, how is `common.analysis.base_analysis` being imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following changes to the calling python run.py script fixed it;

```
from logger.logger import Logger
```